# Database for making employee details

Tags: java, jsp

In below File I done some coding to make a jdbc connection. And I am using a xampp server for that.

ConnectionProvider.java

```
package com.employeerecord.helper;

import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionProvider {
//method GetConnection
    private static Connection connection;
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            //if connection is null then only it get created
            if(connection==null) {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/emprecord","root","");  //Driver for Connection
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

In Below code I make a frontend of the jsp page and put some dummy values. But I'am getting an error of *"ConnectionProvider cannot be resolved"* and does not having an connection.

index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>

<!-- All CSS -->

<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- All JS -->

<script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<%  Connection connection =  ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
    out.println(connection);
    %>
<%@include file="navbar.jsp" %><br><br><br>
                    <!-- Table -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>All Employees In Our Company Are Listed Here</h3>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"> EmployeeID </th>
                        <th scope="col"> Name </th>
                        <th scope="col"> Skills </th>
                        <th scope="col"> Address </th>
                        <th scope="col"> Gender </th>
                        <th scope="col"> Salary </th>
                        <th scope="col"> BirthDate </th>
                        <th scope="col"> Edit </th>
                        <th scope="col"> Delete </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>xyz</td>
                        <td>Java</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>40,000</td>
                        <td>11/11/0000</td>
                        <td>Edit</td>
                        <td>Delete</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error

I'am doing a connection between the jsp file and mysql server using xampp.
[Erron I am Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7emX.png)

Comment: Why do you want to put your database stuff directly in the view? Separate the concerns to help make the code easier to change and understand. Have your database layer return objects that you pass into the JSP.

Comment: I think you should split into MVC pattern, document here
[here](https://www.javatpoint.com/mvc-architecture-in-java#:~:text=The%20Model%2DView%2DController%20(,presentation%20information%20and%20control%20information.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't imported ConnectionProvider
you should add it

```
<%@page import="com.employeerecord.helper.ConnectionProvider"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.jsp`, There is no import for `ConnectionManager`.

I recommend that you don't use `Connection` in the view.

I wish you could separate the view and the database area.

Here is reference for separating the view and the database area.

> https://www.quora.com/Why-are-separate-views-necessary-in-database-applications